# Error Queue implementation using Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, queue

I am trying to impliment Queue using linked list but it goes stops unexpectidly.
could not find why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
```

Class Node for creating a node.

```
class Node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
    };
```

Queue Class containing operations for Queue.

```
class Queue{
private:
    Node* front = NULL;
    Node* rear = NULL;
public:
    void enQueue(int x){
    Node* temp = NULL;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = NULL;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
    }
    void dequeue()
    {
        Node* temp = front;
        if(front == NULL)
        {
            cout << "No list found." << endl;
            return;
        }
        if(front == rear){
            front = rear = NULL;
        }
        else{
            front = front->next;
        }
        delete temp;
    }
};
```

main function goes here

```
int main(){
    Queue a;
    a.enQueue(45);
    a.dequeue();
    a.dequeue();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void enQueue(int x){
  Node* temp = NULL;   //Node* temp = new Node;
  temp->data = x;      //BOOM
  temp->next = NULL;
  if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
    front = rear = NULL;  //What?
    return;
  }
  rear->next = temp;
  rear = temp;
}
```

You are assigning to an invalid address.

This will only stop the program from "stopping unexpectidly". There are still bugs though.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you enqueue a node, you're dereferencing a null pointer

```
void enQueue(int x){
    Node* temp = NULL;
    temp->data = x; // Wrong
```

dereferencing a null pointer yields [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your enqueue function. Make the following changes:

```
void enQueue(int x){
    Node* temp = new Node();//you need to create this variable and not set it to NULL
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL && rear == NULL){
        front = rear = temp;
        return;
    }
    rear->next = temp;
    rear = temp;
    }
```

Now your program will behave as expected